# how to add button to an exist column and displayed in the whole row

Tags: c#, winforms, button, datagridview

I'm working with `GridView` I need to add button to an **existing** column (turn an existing column to buttoncolumn) **not** add new column with buttons. my column called `Volunteers`.

see the code below:

```
    public void showCourse()
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Course_ID],[Course_Name],[Course_Type],[Course_Hours],[Course_Duration],[Course_Place],[Trainer_ID],[Volunteers] FROM [VolunteersAffairs].[dbo].[Course_Info]", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet dats = new DataSet();
        da.SelectCommand = com;
        da.Fill(dats, "Course_Info");
        dataGridViewShowCourse.DataSource = dats.Tables["Course_Info"];
        DataGridViewButtonXColumn bcx =
        dataGridViewShowCourse.Columns["Volunteers"] as DataGridViewButtonColumn;// Like I did nothing
        bcx.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        bcx.Text = "ADD";
        bcx.Name = "MyButton";
    }
```

the error show: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I know add new column with button but I dont want do that, I need to add button to an existing column. The code for add new column with button like below

```
        DataGridViewButtonColumn col = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        col.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        col.Text = "ADD";
        col.Name = "MyButton";
        dataGridViewShowCourse.Columns.Add(col);
```

Thanks

Comment: do you mean you want to turn an existing column to buttoncolumn? or just turn some cells into buttoncells? Note that all the cells of a buttoncolumn are buttoncells.

Comment: that looks like impossible because buttoncolumn and textboxcolumn are really different, unless you use some custom paint for the existing textboxcolumn

Comment: the existing column may be a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` not a `DataGridViewButtonColumn`. So **What is the type of the existing column**?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41298/discussion-between-many-mar-and-king-king)

Comment: Which column you want to turn into a `DataGridViewButtonColumn`, in fact all your columns are auto-generated, I think you just want one of those columns to be buttonColumn, why not add or insert new column?

Comment: The last one called Volunteers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add new button column **before** setting your DataSource with correct settings like this:

```
public void showCourse()
{
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Course_ID],[Course_Name],[Course_Type],[Course_Hours],[Course_Duration],[Course_Place],[Trainer_ID],[Volunteers] FROM [VolunteersAffairs].[dbo].[Course_Info]", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet dats = new DataSet();
    da.SelectCommand = com;
    da.Fill(dats, "Course_Info");

    if(dataGridViewShowCourse.Columns["MyButton"] == null){
      var col = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
      col.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
      col.Text = "ADD";
      col.Name = "MyButton";
      col.DataPropertyName = "Volunteers"; //<-- this is very important
      dataGridViewShowCourse.Columns.Add(col);
    }
    dataGridViewShowCourse.DataSource = dats.Tables["Course_Info"];
}
```

However I suggest you should remove the `Volunteers` from the `SELECT` and add the new button column yourself.

Set the column to the last:

```
col.DisplayIndex =  dataGridViewShowCourse.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                                          .Count(col=>col.Visible) - 1;
```

Comment: yes it is done, but the column shown at the first column, can I put it as the latest column. And thanks for your suggestion I really appreciate it

Comment: @ManyMar see the update, it's a little tricky. The only property we have is `DisplayIndex`, otherwise you have to remove and `Insert` it back.